# chmod fails when using sudo

Tags: sudo, chmod

I have a program that requires changing the system time with `settimeofday` and then changing the permissions of a file with `chmod`. This program must be run with sudo to successfully change the date.

However, **chmod fails** when I run the program with sudo with "Operation Not Permitted." If I run chmod *without* sudo, it works fine.

Why does sudo work for changing the time of day, but not chmod?  I am the owner of the file.
How can I get chmod to work in my program?

```
char* file;
struct timeval now;

//.....

now.tv_sec=866208142;
now.tv_usec=290944;

if(settimeofday(&now, NULL) < 0) 
{
   printf("settimeofday() failed, ""errno = %d\n",errno);
   return -1;
}

if (chmod(file, S_IRWXU|S_IRGRP|S_IXGRP|S_IROTH) < 0)
{
  printf(error in chmod(%s, %d) - %d (%s)\n", file, 
     S_IRWXU|S_IRGRP|S_IXGRP|S_IROTH, errno, strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: Please post the script lines you are referring to.

Comment: Please show the command that you use.